# contextmenu for particular line in a multi-line view listview 

Tags: android

I have a listview with each item in the list having 2 lines .I want to create a context menu for it such that the header of the context menu should be the text in the first line of the selected item.How to achieve this.Here the name "dfsflk" was hardcoded.I want  the program to identify the selected item and display the name as the title.

```
@Override     
  public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
  {  
      super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();         
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.contextmenu, menu);
      menu.setHeaderTitle( "dfsdlk");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear enough. 
Can you try to give us more info what do you want to do.

if you want to set header of context menu you can do this by calling "setHeaderTitle("some title")" on onCreateContextMenu method. Like this:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        ProjectUser selected = projectUserList.get(info.position);
        menu.setHeaderTitle(selected.Name);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.project_users_contextmenu, menu);

    }
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.I have created a list view with say 5 items each with 2 textviews(with vertical orientation).Suppose i press and hold one of the item i want the string in the first textview of the corresponding item to be the headeer of the context menu.

Comment: Oh i see.Well if you use list to fill listview from code, you can get specific item trough its position (like i did in code above."ProjectUser selected = projectUserList.get(info.position);") and then simply call setHeaderTitle and pass string from item.